# Visual Studio debugger sets the upper half of AVX registers to zero

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, avx

When debugging some code using AVX, I was getting results which made no sense. I reduced my program to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        static float v[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
        __m256 v8 = _mm256_load_ps(v);
        std::cout << v8.m256_f32[2] << v8.m256_f32[5];
    }
}
```

When I run this program, it prints `36` endlessly, which is correct (it prints `3`, and then `6`). If I set a breakpoint in a debugger inside the loop, and do single-step, it prints `30`. If I remove the breakpoint and continue the program, it starts printing `36` again. I see the same behavior in Release/Debug, Win32/x86 (4 combinations).

To be able to use AVX, I set "Enable Enhanced Instruction Set" to "Advanced Vector Extensions (/arch:AVX)" in Configuration Properties - C/C++ - Code Generation. Did I forget to set some other configuration?

As a result of this behavior, I cannot use the debugger to debug my real program (not included here). This is annoying.

Did I do anything wrong? Can I fix this behavior?

My Visual Studio is: MS Visual Studio Professional 2017, version 15.9.3.

Comment: FWIW, I am not observing that behavior on MSVC2019, x64 Debug/Release. I get 36 both when running or stepping through.

Comment: If you look at the asm code-gen, MSVC with those options should be generating normal AVX instructions with proper vzeroupper usage, like on https://godbolt.org/z/YMobhKK56.  (Using `-O2`, we see VS19.28 keeping the vector on the stack and doing a YMM load + shuffle for each union-element access, not taking advantage of call-preserved xmm5..15).  Are you building for 32-bit or x86-64?  Certainly sounds like a debugger problem, though; that code is legal and should be well-defined on MSVC, and changing the behaviour when single-stepping or not is a huge red flag.

Comment: I see the same behavior in Release/Debug, Win32/x86 (4 combinations). I do see `vzeroupper` in the disassembly, but it's in a funny location inside the loop. I'll go tweak my code some more to see if I can make sense of it.

Comment: Possibly OT: Doesn't `_mm256_load_ps` require 32-byte boundary alignment? Which doesn't seem to be guaranteed in your case.

Comment: can't reproduce in visual studio 2017 15.9.37

Comment: I used `_mm256_loadu_ps` originally; changed to `_mm256_load_ps` later. Same behavior for both.

Comment: The `vzeroupper` is there to avoid AVX/SSE transition stalls when calling a function after using YMM registers.  The standard convention is to have clean uppers when calling / returning, unless the function actually takes an arg in a YMM register and thus can be assumed not to use legacy SSE instructions.  MSVC is dumb and uses YMM registers in the process of extracting an element from a vector in memory, so needs a `vzeroupper` to avoid a performance risk.  Your correct results when not single-stepping prove that the `vzeroupper` isn't the cause of the problem.

Comment: @DanielLangr: MSVC (and ICC) *always* use alignment-not-required AVX loads/stores like `vmovups`, even when you use the alignment-required intrinsic.  So they remove the possibility of finding misaligned data by intentionally using alignment-required loads/stores in a debug build (where they won't get folded into memory source operands for other instructions that don't require alignment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual studio 2017 15.9.7 [fixes a bug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#issues-fixed-in-1597) which corrupts AVX/MPX/AVX512 registers while Debugging, you should update to the latest version, 15.9.3 is nearly 3 years old.

Comment: Didn't try it (updating Visual Studio is a separate nightmare) but this must be the answer!

Comment: @anatolyg Updating within the current release has never caused me any problems, it mainly just contains bug fixes and more importantly for your code security fixes